# Protect access phone's settings with a password programmatically?

Tags: android, passwords, settings

Is it possible to implement an application that programmatically protects the access to a phone's "Settings" with a password ?

Comment: Or is it possible catch user's click on the android screen "Settings" ?? So i could start a lockScreen...

Comment: I would protect my application from Uninstall... is it possible also use Device Administration Policy ??

Answer (score 2):

The answer for you may lie in [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) for Android

Also refer an example http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.html

Comment: Second link doesn't work. please post another one. thank you.